# Reading from file into vector<T> line by line works incorrect for binary data C++

Tags: c++, templates, binary, stdvector

There is a template to fill `vector <T>` from the file:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void fill_vector_from_file(const std::string  &filePath, std::vector<T, A> & target)
{
    std::ifstream is(filePath, std::ifstream::in);

    is.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end);
    std::size_t size = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0, std::ifstream::beg);
    target.reserve(size);

std::string line;
while (std::getline(is, line))
{
    std::istringstream line_in(line);
    while (line_in)
    {
        T val = 0;
        if (line_in >> val)
        {
            target.push_back(val);
        }
    }
}
is.close();
```

Data in files can be int or binary and stored one number per line , for example:
For **int**:

```
2 
-3
4
```

and for **binary**:

```
010
111
001
```

When I checked template with `std::vector<int> v1` for integers
and `std::vector<unsigned char> v2` , result of `v2[0]` was `0` instead of `010`.
(I supposed, that I should use unsigned char for to store binary)

Question: Is there any way to modify template , so the result of `v2[0]` will be as expected (`010`).

Comment: `unsigned char` is only 1 byte in size. You are reading the file as a text file, line by line. Reading a line like `"2"` as an `int` works fine, of course, since `operator>>` supports that conversion. But you can't read in a line like `"010"` as an `unsigned char`. The STL has no I/O manipulator for reading binary-digit strings. The code shown is going to read the individual chars, so it will read `'0'`, `'1'`, `'0'` instead. You will have to add extra code logic to read the `"010"` line and apply your own conversion logic to turn it into an `unsigned char` (0x02).

Comment: What a shame. 
Thank you :D

Comment: You have to read second file knowing that data is stored as string which represents binary. Currently it doesn't seem like you have this kind of detection in your template.

Comment: _>>I supposed, that I should use unsigned char for to store binary_ You can try `std::bitset<3>` for type `T` and then convert it to `unsigned char` later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd file seems to contain strings of binary format. Let's assume they are always 3 bits long, in which case if you use `std::bitset<3>` you will read each number in full. If you use `unsigned char` then you will only read one digit at a time. Here is your function, slightly modified with examples of reading different files (format of which you know before hand I suppose). As a bonus there is also example of how to convert `std::bitset` vector into `unsigned char` should you need it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm> // std::transform

template<typename T, typename A>
void fill_vector_from_file(std::string const &filePath, std::vector<T, A> &vec)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filePath);
    T val;

    while (ifs >> val)
        vec.push_back(val);
}

int main()
{
    // make sample files
    std::ofstream ofs("myfile.txt");
    ofs << "2\n" << "-3\n" << "4\n";
    ofs.close();
    ofs.open("myfile2.txt");
    ofs << "010\n" << "111\n" << "001\n";
    ofs.close();


    // fill <int> vector
    std::vector<int> vi;
    fill_vector_from_file("myfile.txt", vi);
    // print int vector
    for (auto n : vi)
        std::cout << n << std::endl;


    // fill <bitset> vector 
    std::vector<std::bitset<3>> vbs;
    fill_vector_from_file("myfile2.txt", vbs);
    // print bitset vector
    for (auto n : vbs)
        std::cout << n << std::endl;


    // [OPTIONAL] convert to vector <unsigned char>
    std::vector<unsigned char> vuc(vbs.size());
    std::transform(vbs.begin(), vbs.end(), vuc.begin(),
        [](std::bitset<3> const &bs) -> unsigned char { return static_cast<unsigned char>(bs.to_ulong()); });
    // print vector <unsigned char>
    for (auto n : vuc)
        std::cout << int(n) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Working demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=42aa04e34e4194c1

```
2
-3
4
010
111
001
2
7
1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with this code, but your original question has the following answer:

**Converting a 0-1 ASCII string to integer.** Your code `line_in >> val` for val being of type `unsigned char` reads a single character, like '0' and '1'. You want to convert an ASCII string made of '0's and '1's, which forms a base-2 number, into an integer.
In this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596988/binary-string-to-integer-with-atoi#23597029) you find that `val = std::stoi(line, nullptr, 2);` does that for you.

So, neither "-3" nor "101" are *integers* but *strings* that represent integers in base-10 and base-2, and stoi() does the conversion to integers for you. In case of base-10, however, the iostream `operator>>()` works as well. (You may also have a look into `std::setbase()`.)